# Get Fetch_Assoc results by numerical index

Tags: php

Is there a way to access the results of 'fetch_assoc()'
by number? For instance, I'd expect the following to give me 

1.) Array

2.) 25

3.) 'First Element'

Instead, it throws the following error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs_notesale\index.php on line 22

Any idea how to do this?
thanks
JW

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('CONN','USER','PW','DB');
$rs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `checklist`");
$r_count = $rs->num_rows;
$c_count = $rs->field_count;
```

`?>`
`...`

```
    <?php
        for($i=0;$i<$r_count;$i++)
        {
        $row = $rs->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "1 - ".$row."<br />";
            echo "2 - ".count($row)."<br />";
            echo "3 - ".$row[0]."<br />";
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have called `fetch_assoc()`, and yet expect the result to be indexed?

Try [`fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) or [`fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: I was just gonna answer the same, but i thought lets refresh first before posting ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = $rs->fetch_assoc(); 
$keys = array_keys($row);
echo $row[$keys[0]];
```

Though why you want to retrieve assoc and then access by numeric key escapes me

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful for "looking ahead" at the next/upcoming row that WILL be fetched in the next WHILE loop iteration.  It's useful at the end of a while iteration to see if the current iteration is the *last* of a group and then print a footer or subtotal 
before proceeding with the rest of the Results